# How can I change the name of my app in the Soundcloud Developer console?

Tags: soundcloud

I have a Soundcloud Developer account, but I want to change the name of my app. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to change the name of an existing app through the console.  There is also no way to create a new app at this time.  You're stuck with the apps you have and their current names.